# How to set a parameter value based on the app settings key value inside a web.config

Tags: c#, web-config

I have the following code inside a web.config and I'd like some way of setting the Parameter "NoHeader" to the value of the app settings key "ShowHeader" such that the former would be set to true. The best guess I have is that I use code to read the value from the ConfigurationManager and somehow write it back to NoHeader but I don't know how to do that if that's the case.

```
<Telerik.Reporting>
    <Extensions>
      <Render>
        <Extension name="CSV">
          <Parameters>
            <Parameter name="NoHeader" value="false" />
          </Parameters>
        </Extension>
      </Render>
    </Extensions>
  </Telerik.Reporting>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ShowHeader" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

We use a method that changes the showHeader key on deployment, but I'm not able to modify the NoHeader portion directly. I'm using C# for my code, any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using merging your config files?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, they're in the same web.config file.

Comment: Why can’t you change you deployment?

Comment: At worst case I'll be just updating the Noheader manually before a deployment, I'm just hoping someone has a way to do what I'd like so that it can be more dynamic.